# Download text file and set components?

Tags: vb.net

How to make vb download a text file and then read all the lines to see what components are available and then set them on `form`? Text file would contain something like this:

- [1] = number of component, `pyc_file` as the component name to display to user. and last is a link from where the file is downloaded.

The `pyc_file` should be displayed next on a `checkbox`.

```
[1];pyc_file;www.mediafire.com/abcd1234/_init_.pyc;
```

I don't know how to explain it very well. I hope you understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it now :-) 
Wasn't actually that hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own type to parse the parts like this:

[image]

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim LineToParse As String =
        "[1];pyc_file;www.mediafire.com/abcd1234/_init_.pyc;"

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

        Dim Comp As Component = Me.GetComponent(LineToParse)

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        sb.AppendFormat("Line: {0}", LineToParse)
        sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)

        sb.AppendFormat("Index: {0}", CStr(Comp.Index))
        sb.AppendLine()
        sb.AppendFormat("Name: {0}", Comp.Name)
        sb.AppendLine()
        sb.AppendFormat("Url: {0}", Comp.URL)

        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString, "Component information",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Parses a comma-delimited component text-line and returns a Component Object.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="ComponentLine">Indicates the component line to parse.</param>
    ''' <returns>Component.</returns>
    Friend Function GetComponent(ByVal ComponentLine As String) As Component

        Dim ComponentParts As IEnumerable(Of String) =
            ComponentLine.Split(";"c)

        Dim Index As Integer =
            Integer.Parse(ComponentParts(0).
                          Replace("[", String.Empty).Replace("]", String.Empty))

        Dim Name As String =
            ComponentParts(1)

        Dim URL As Uri =
            New Uri(If(Not ComponentParts(2).StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
                       String.Format("http://{0}", ComponentParts(2)),
                       ComponentParts(2)))

        Return New Component With
               {
                 .Index = Index,
                 .Name = Name,
                 .URL = URL
               }

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A component.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend NotInheritable Class Component

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Indicates the number of component.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property Index As Integer

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Indicates the component name to display to user.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property Name As String

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Indicates a link from where the file is downloaded.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property URL As Uri

    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: and how to make it show only as many checkboxes, as there are available files? (so there wouldn't be empty ones)